# Count how many fields where cleansed and which fields on SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools

I'm doing an exercise in which I have to clean data from a Flat File Source and write it on my Database. I have already managed to clean all of the fields by using some data quality rules for each field and also generate error codes which I write to a different table when a rule is broken.

My problem is that for the final step of the exercise I have to generate some Power BI graphics in which it shows how many fields were fixed from the source and which fields where cleansed. The only thing that I have thought compares the DB table to the flat file source or maybe do something with script components but I don't really think that those are really good solutions.

Has anybody encountered this problem? if somebody could point me out for info for something like this, it would be great. Thanks!

Comment: How big is your file in terms of size in MBs or Gbs ?

Comment: A few kb, it's just a .txt with 10 lines of 8 fields

Answer (score 1):

If I am facing a similar issue, I will do this in three steps:

1. Importing data without any transformation to a staging table
2. Cleaning data and loading it into the destination table
3. Comparing staging and destination table to get how many values were fixed.

Comment: That seems like a good solution, but now i have another doubt. How do you compare the two tables? Using something like a stored procedure? Or something in SSIS?

Comment: @bojackhorseman99 you have to write a query for each column (note that if the data doesn't contain a unique ID, you have to add one to use it in comparison)

Answer (score 1):

From design standpoint - establishing a key is central before starting to clean.

Use could use SSIS derived column transformation to create a business key that is a concatenation of available fields to create a unique key, using FindString function and string functions.

Similar to the above step add a column in your staging table or use a derived column (depending on if you are using sql cleanup or ssis tasks to cleanup) to indicate if it was cleaned or not.